# jekyll server --livereload throwing error

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, bundler, github-pages, eventmachine

I have been through the following links and have tried but didn't get any help:-
[Cannot load Ruby EventMachine in Rails console - no such file to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161142/cannot-load-ruby-eventmachine-in-rails-console-no-such-file-to-load)
[Using Live Reload with Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395526/using-live-reload-with-jekyll)
[Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682575/unable-to-load-the-eventmachine-c-extension-to-use-the-pure-ruby-reactor)

From the 2nd question mentioned above, I understand that `--livereload` comes with `jekyll v3.7+`.
My machine has the following:

```
Pkg / Cmd       Versions
---------       -------------------------------------------------------------
npm    -v       6.14.13
ruby   -v       ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x64-mingw32]
gem    -v       3.2.22
jekyll -v       jekyll 4.2.0
bundle -v       Bundler version 2.2.23
```

Now when I execute `bundle exec jekyll serve` or `jekyll serve`, I get the following output:-

```
PS C:\Users\Vedant\source\repos\Mine\phougatv.github.io> jekyll serve
Configuration file: C:/Users/blah/blah/phougatv.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/blah/blah/phougatv.github.io
       Destination: C:/Users/blah/blah/phougatv.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.859 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/Users/blah/blah/phougatv.github.io'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

And when I execute `bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload` or `jekyll serve --livereload`, I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Vedant\source\repos\Mine\phougatv.github.io> jekyll serve --livereload
Configuration file: C:/Users/blah/blah/phougatv.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/blah/blah/phougatv.github.io
       Destination: C:/Users/blah/blah/phougatv.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.701 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/Users/blah/blah/phougatv.github.io'
                    ------------------------------------------------
      Jekyll 4.2.0   Please append `--trace` to the `serve` command
                     for any additional information or backtrace.
                    ------------------------------------------------
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:41:in `require': cannot load such file -- sorted_set (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/em-websocket-0.5.2/lib/em-websocket.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/em-websocket-0.5.2/lib/em-websocket.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/live_reload_reactor.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/live_reload_reactor.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:143:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:143:in `register_reload_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:98:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

After getting the above-mentioned error I followed [Answer-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682575/unable-to-load-the-eventmachine-c-extension-to-use-the-pure-ruby-reactor#answer-53080143) & [Answer-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682575/unable-to-load-the-eventmachine-c-extension-to-use-the-pure-ruby-reactor#answer-65547010), and added `gem "eventmachine"` to the `Gemfile` but they didn't seems to solve my problem. One of these answers gave the error: `'require': cannot load such file -- sorted_set (LoadError)`, to resolve this I did `gem install sorted_set`(SortedSet has been removed), but then other error message was displayed. After trying all these answer, I think I am nowhere near to the correct approach.

**Question**: How do I execute: `bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload` or `jekyll serve --livereload` successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58683890/16465064) which was in one of the posts you linked which solved the problem for me at least. You may have already tried it, though.